# How to Import a namespaced TypeScript class in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

Given a TypeScript class which is namespaced as a TS module, in a file CoolApps.Utilities.ts:

```
    module CoolApps {
        export class Utilities {
            myMethod(){
               alert("something awesome");
            }
        }
    }
```

The class works in a normal TypeScript app but I'm trying to figure our the correct way to reference this class in Angular 2. How do I use this in an Angular 2 app (Ionic 2 in the case)? So far the following doesn't resolve so I'm probably getting the syntax wrong:

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {Utilities} from '../../core/CoolApps.Utilities';
```

Using a reference like so will allow the editor to see the code as valid, but Angular can't resolve it (maybe import only works for Angular specific modules?):

```
///<reference path="../../core/mapping/OCM.Mapping.ts"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import :

```
import {CoolApps} from '../../core/CoolApps.Utilities';
```

Class usage example

```
let util : CoolApps.Utilities  = new CoolApps.Utilities();
```

You can also remove module declaration from CoolApps.Utilities.ts and transform the import like this :

```
import * as CoolApps from '../../core/CoolApps.Utilities';
```

Comment: How about if the CoolApps namespacing is split across multiple files, e.g. CoolApps.ImageProcessing or CoolApps.PhotoUpload? Just not sure if namespacing into modules is even worth preserving?